# how to switch between panels during designing phase in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a simple applications using c# in visual studio. How to switch between several panels during design process, Normally panels will be overlapped . so can any one help me out of this . Please avoid suggest using tabs, i know to use tabs. Answer for panels

Comment: there is no such mechanism to switch between panels. What you can do is make youre window large enough and place all your panels on it. And when you are done with that then reduce your window size to normal. Or resize panel to small once you are done with it and place it somewhere near the edge. And then design other.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Document Outline Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

> In Visual Studio, on the View menu, click Other Windows and then click
>   Document Outline.

Answer (score 2):

Bring To Front / Send To Back - think its under the view or edit menu.  Is definately on the panel context menu

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53318/C-Custom-Control-Featuring-a-Collapsible-Panel
[How to create collapsible panels as custom controls in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521271/how-to-create-collapsible-panels-as-custom-controls-in-winforms)
    Hope this will help you..